# android - add TableRow (containing LinearLayout) to Table

Tags: android

I have a complicated table, so I would like to make one row a little more flexible for adding a button or text view, so I have the following code for adding TableRow to Table. I am trying to set LinearLayout to TableRow programmatically, but the row does not show up when I run it. I'd appreciated if somebody can point what the problem is.

```
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        final CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
        checkbox.setPadding(10, 5, 0, 0);
        checkbox.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 15);
        checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String item_clicked_on = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item_clicked_on, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(" " + count + ". " + baby.getName());
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 14);
        tv.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 0);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String item_clicked_on = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item_clicked_on, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        checkbox.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(tr.getContext());
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout.addView(checkbox, new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearLayout.addView(tv, new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tableRow.addView(linearLayout);

        table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I am trying to make it look like this xml.

```
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Choice 1" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding linear layout to **tableRow** .

```
tableRow.addView(linearLayout);
```

But you are adding table row **tr** to Table **table**

```
table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I think you have to add **tableRow** to **table**. Once check it.

Comment: Don't I have to add linearLayout to TableRow and TableRow to Table?

Comment: @user826323 Just check the variables **tableRow** and **tr**. Which one you have to add to **table**. Read the above answer carefully.